# Can't get multiple result in td

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem in displaying the result in `td inside table`. I want to display all rows coming from the database.
I have code but it results only one `row`.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "trackingsys"); 
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
            }
            $query="SELECT * from role" ; 
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
                echo '<tr>'; 
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>" . $row['RoleName'] . "</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>" . $row['RoleDesc'] . "</td>"; 
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
            mysqli_close($con); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I edited this `code and put the ending tag` `</td>`. But still it results only `one row.`

Comment: You are missing the closing `</td>` tags (three times).  That could be causing your display problem.

Comment: I edited the code. but still same result..

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: What do you mean with var_dump($result)?

Comment: @CameronHurd good on you for editing, but please don't insert random spaces into function names etc. Rolled back.

Comment: Hey @scrowler - noticed the mistake and immediately corrected. You're quicker, though.

Comment: Google `var_dump()`. It's a function that lets you see the contents of a variable.  So in your case, right after you get the results, but before you start your `while`, you can insert a line `var_dump($results)` and it will output the contents of the `$results` variable to the screen.  You can then edit your question, including those contents, and then we can understand if the results is the problem, or there's something else going on.

Comment: @user0206 your code is working, i have checked it...Now please confirm that there is more than one row inserted in database and your ID field is set as auto increment.